# Evaluate Improper Integral: $f(b) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\exp{-b \left(\frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{|x|}\right)}^{-1}}$

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, improper-integrals, machine-learning

In machine learning, we often want to learn some unknown conditional distribution from data. For example, suppose we have some dataset $D$ of feature $x_i \in R^n$ and labels $y_i \in R$ generated according to some distribution $p(y|x)$. We can represent the conditional distribution $p(y|x)$ using a large parameterized function $f_\theta$ (ie, a neural network) which maps features $x$ onto simple probability densities (ie, a mixture of gaussians). Let's call the parameters of our neural network $\theta$ and our network outputs $\psi$, so that $f_\theta(x) = \psi$. We then choose $\theta = \underset{\theta}{\arg \min} \sum_{(x,y)\in D}{}\log p_\psi(y|\psi = f_\theta(x))$

When we choose $p_\psi$ to be a mixture of gaussians, the likelihood function is easy to compute and differentiate. However, using a gaussian density in this way will lead to poor results when our dataset has outliers, pairs $(x, y)$ that are related differently than pairs with similar $x$ features. To make training more robust to these outliers, we could use a heavier tailed distribution, such as a mixture of laplace distributions. The laplace distributions would cause training to be more robust, but would decrease the overall precision in representing $p(y|x)$ with $p_\psi$.

We often use a [huber loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss) to get the advantages of both the squared loss (gaussian) and absolute loss (laplace).  However, the normalization factor for the density corresponding to the huber loss involves several evaluations of $erf$, which is undesireable.

The integrand in this question gives a density similar to the huber density. My hope is that it is possible to compute using only a few elementary functions.

For the same reasons, I would be just as happy to learn $g(b) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\exp{-b \sqrt{1 + x^2}}},$ or any function $h(b) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\exp{-b L(x)}}$ with $L(x) \overset{x\rightarrow 0}{\approx} x^2$ and $L(x) \overset{x\rightarrow \infty}{\approx} x$, as long as $L(x), h(b)$ can be computed efficiently.

Comment: If $L(x)=\sqrt{1+x^2}$ then $L(x)=1+x^2/2+O(x^4)$ for small $x$, so $L(x)$ does not satisfiy $L(x)\approx x$ for small $x$ (Maybe you did not mean that either?).

Comment: @mickep Thanks, I had it backward. I want linear behavior for large x for robustness, and quadratic for small x.

Comment: As an initial attempt, have you already tried splitting your integration interval in half (note that the integrand is even)?